# Is $∃!x(x^2 = 1)$ true?

Tags: logic

for a question that I have it is asking for the truth value of $∃!x(x^2 = 1)$ my instincts tell me no because there are 2 values that make it true. Am I right?

Comment: It depends upon your universe. If you are dealing with integers then you are correct. If you are dealing with natural numbers then we can no longer consider negative values.

Comment: Let's not forget [split complex numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on $x$. If $x > 0$, or $x < 0$ then it's true. But if $x$ is any real number or complex number, then it's false since there are $2$ answers: $x = \pm 1$. And let's say if $x < -3$, then there is no solution.

Comment: Also, if $x>1003$, then there exists no solution.

Comment: It's an XOR situation